# NgRedux + Angular + select triggered on subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngredux

I'm using redux in my angular App for weeks now, but I just noticed something about it :

When I'm selecting a part of my store to monitor changes, let's say like that :

In the ngOnInit() of app.component.ts

```
this.ngRedux.select(s => s.counter).subscribe((counter: number) => {
    console.log(counter)
});
```

The console.log(counter) is executed each time my counter value change, that's ok, that's how it suppose to works.

BUT, the callback is also executed when I first subscribe. 
So it's like that :

1. Enter onNgInit()
2. Executing select()
3. Executing Subscribe()
4. Executing my callback
5. ------- Later when counter change : -------
6. Executing my callback

My problem is that I dont want my callback to be executed on step 4, because the store did not change !

Is there an issue in my understanding ? Is is supposed to work like that ? If yes : Can I do something to change it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the standard behaviour of `.subscribe()`. The only thing you can do is to compare your current value of `counter` with the new one and only react on it if changes happened.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I was wondering if it's the standard behavior on .subscribe() or if I did something wrong. I will try to solve this by my slef as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any idea where is it mentioned in the docs?